# Google Play API returning "400 Bad Request"

Tags: api, validation, google-play, product

Below is my code:

```
public class MyTestCase {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ListApks.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME),
                "ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME cannot be null or empty!");

        // Create the API service.
        final AndroidPublisher service = AndroidPublisherHelper.init(
                ApplicationConfig.APPLICATION_NAME, ApplicationConfig.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
        final AndroidPublisher.Edits edits = service.edits();

        // Create a new edit to make changes.
        AndroidPublisher.Edits.Insert editRequest = edits
                .insert(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME,
                        null /** no content */);
        AppEdit appEdit = editRequest.execute();


        Get purchases = service.purchases().products().get(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME, "consumer", "bg46378");
        System.out.println(purchases);
        ProductPurchase purchase = purchases.execute();

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        log.error("Exception was thrown while updating listing", ex);
    }
}
}
```

Problem is that i keep getting:

```
SEVERE: Exception was thrown while updating listing
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code" : 400,
   "errors" : [ {
   "domain" : "global",
   "message" : "Invalid Value",
   "reason" : "invalid"
 } ],
 "message" : "Invalid Value"
 }
```

I'm not too sure if that has anything to do with the token parameter (which I will be using later on for the payload).

EDIT:  I realized that I needed to put the purchaseToken into the token parameter of GET.  The purchaseToken came from the payload on the mobile client.  I still get the same result however.  The purchaseToken I put in looks like

```
 String pt = "amopiilkhbjihjkfpbobeimo.AO-J1OzmDyihgfHLIPzDWfacU6EVf3rCj7LCbfypeO066DXddCoMgX7UeHesl32HA4K_x6rkYDEMR1e4rfhCYEMcc_8Xx_eySLIZ6BejrH8eJyZ0IhVREa0";
```

Comment: Anyone?  I'm stuck until I can solve this.  I've tried everything from instructions, but still getting this error.  Just a standard procedure, so I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem.  Just needed to do a copy and paste rather than trying to copy by eyesight.  Managed it by copying the purchase token from the client app to the server app.